# Tampermonkey (Firefox) user scripts storage location

Tags: firefox, tampermonkey

I'm looking for where Tampermonkey user scripts are stored on Firefox. I have a corrupt profile which I successfully replaced with an old backup, but I want to try to recover my scripts from the corrupt profile.

Edit: To add to the accepted answer, to find the exact path on your particular installation, go to `☰ → Add-ons and Themes → ⛭ → Debug Add-ons`, then under the extension in question (in this case Tampermonkey), the ID is shown in "`Manifest URL`." Inserting that ID after `moz-extension+++` gives the correct path.

Comment: check `about:debugging#/runtime/this-firefox`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you'll be able get exact location as an answer, because the path to the database will be different between computers.

In my test case it's in:
 *`<profile folder>`*`\storage\default\moz-extension+++b703a71d-c069-4111-88ad-71e1fea6540a^userContextId=4294967295\idb\3647222921wleabcEoxlt-eengsairo.sqlite`